# Errors with Peterson's Algorithm

Tags: c, linux, critical-section

Hey I was wondering if someone could help me figure out why my implementation of Peterson's Algo isn't working.

Currently my output is:

```
From Process total = [number > 100,000]
Child with ID -1 has just exited
Child with ID [Child ID] has just exited
     End of Program
From Process 2 total = [number > 200,000]
Child with ID -1 has just exited
```

My output should be along the lines of:

```
From Process 1: total = 60234. 
From Process 2: total = 100000.
Child with ID 2412 has just exited. 
Child with ID 2411 has just exited.
     End of  Program.
```

For some reason one of my child processes has an ID of -1 which means there is some sort of error (I think). I have no idea what's going on with that. I'm still confused how this algorithm ever works because if turn never changes, how does the process ever get access to the critical section?

My code is as follows:

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


typedef struct
{
  int value;
  int flag[2] = {FALSE, FALSE};
  int turn = 0;
} shared_mem;


shared_mem *total;



       void process1 ()
{
  int k = 0;

  while (k < 100000)
    {
      total->flag[0] = TRUE;
      total->turn = 1;

      //prevent P1 from access CS
      while(total->flag[1] == TRUE && total->turn == 1)
      {
        int k = 0;
        if(k = 0)
        {
            total->p2Block = total->p2Block + 1;
        }
        k++;
      };

      k++;
      total->value = total->value + 1;

      total->flag[0] = FALSE;
    }

  printf("Process 2 interrupted %d times in critical section by Process 1.\n", total->p2Block);
  printf ("From process1 total = %d\n", total->value);
}

    void process2 ()
{
  int k = 0;

  while (k < 200000)
    {
      total->flag[1] = TRUE;
      total->turn = 0;
      int critical;
      //prevent P2 from accessing CS
      while(total->flag[0] == TRUE && total->turn == 0)
      {
            int k = 0;
            if(k = 0)
            {
                total->p2Block = total->p1Block + 1;
            }
        k++;
      };

      k++;
      total->value = total->value + 1;
      critical++;

      total->flag[1] = FALSE;
    }

  printf("Process 1 interrupted %d times in critical section by Process 2.\n", total->p1Block);
  printf("From process2 total = %d\n", total->value);
}



main()
{
  int   shmid;
  int   pid1;
  int   pid2;
  int   ID;
  int   status;
  int   waitID1, waitID2;

  char *shmadd;
  shmadd = (char *) 0;

/* Create and connect to a shared memory segmentt*/

  if ((shmid = shmget (SHMKEY, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
    {
      perror ("shmget");
      exit (1);
    }


 if ((total = (shared_mem *) shmat (shmid, shmadd, 0)) == (shared_mem *) -1)
    {
      perror ("shmat");
      exit (0);
    }


  total->value = 0;
  total->flag[0] = FALSE;
  total->flag[1] = FALSE;
  total->turn = 0;
  total->p1Block = 0;
  total->p2Block = 0;

  if ((pid1 = fork()) == 0)
    process1();

  if ((pid1 != 0) && (pid2 = fork()) == 0)
    process2();

  do{
    waitID1 = waitpid(pid1, &status, 0);
    waitID2 = waitpid(pid2, &status, 0);
    if(WIFEXITED(status) && waitID1 != -1)
    {
      printf("Child with ID %d has just exited\n", waitID1);
    }
    if(WIFEXITED(status) && waitID2 != -1)
    {
      printf("Child with ID %d has just exited\n", waitID2);
    }
  }while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));  

  if ((pid1 != 0) && (pid2 != 0))
    {

      if ((shmctl (shmid, IPC_RMID, (struct shmid_ds *) 0)) == -1)
      {
        perror ("shmctl");
        exit (-1);
      }
      printf ("\t\t  End of Program.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a userspace program, and not kernel code.  The [tag:linux-kernel] tag is inappropriate.  Try using [tag:linux] instead.

Comment: When -1 is returned by fork, the errno is be set with the code (see [manpage of fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) at Return value).
You can get the error message associated to this errno with [strerror](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror).

Comment: Hey, I actually need to synchronize 2 child processes using Peterson algorithm but it seems very tough to me as I am new to OS concepts. If you got the working code, I would request you to kindly update your question with the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Watch what you share

Your global declarations

```
int flag[2] = {FALSE, FALSE};
int turn = 0;
```

are *not shared memory*.  Your `total` is shared memory because you share it, but the `flag` and `turn` are not.  Each process has its own copy of the `flag` and `turn` and modify only their own copy of it.  Since the synchronization mechanism you're trying to implement (Peterson's Algorithm) relies on both processes modifying the same `flag` and `turn`, it doesn't work.  When one process changes the `flag`, the other doesn't know about it.

**(The above has since been addressed in an edit to the question.)**

Sharing and synchronizing between *processes* is typically more complicated than sharing and synchronizing between *threads*.  The two are different things for different purposes.  If it is possible, I'd consider using threads instead of processes.  This way, sharing memory is trivial.  This problem seems to be an educational exercise, and schools typically teach processes before threads.

### Watch how you share it

You will need to initialize `turn` and `flag` after creating the shared memory, such as where you initialize `total->value = 0;` and not in a `typedef` declaration.

Go through your notes about how to set up shared memory and read through the relevant man pages.

In `smget()` you have a size of `sizeof(int)`, which is not enough for the whole struct.  Personally, I'm against hard coding types in `sizeof()` operators.  I suggest using something like `sizeof(*shared_mem)` and let the compiler figure out what the type and size should be.  It's also easier if you change the declaration for some reason, because you don't have to sift through your code looking for `sizeof()` operators.

### Restructure the `fork()` calls and test the return values

Library functions return values for a reason.  Ignoring what they say is like ignoring alarm bells.  Sometimes such an alarm might help you figure out what is wrong with your program.

There are three return states to check from a `fork()` (check all of them):

- -1, an error occurred
- 0, in child process
- >0, in parent process (with child's PID)

Also, notice that after completing `process1()` and `process2()`, the children return to `main()` and fall through the subsequent instructions, even trying to wait for children they don't have.  This is probably not what you want.

### Check the return value from wait()

The `-1` printed is the return value from [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html).  This means that `wait()` encountered an error.  The likely cause for this is that the calling process has no child to wait for.

From POSIX.1-2008/IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (2013 Ed.) for the function [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html):

> `pid_t wait(int *stat_loc);`
>   `pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *stat_loc, int options);`
>
> . . .
>
> If `wait()` or `waitpid()` return because the status of a child process is available, these functions shall return a value equal to the process ID of the child process. In this case, if the value of the argument `stat_loc` is not a null pointer, information shall be stored in the location pointed to by `stat_loc`.

I am interpreting this to mean that if `wait()` did not "return because the status of a child process is available", then we can not rely on the value written to `stat_loc`.

In other words, you should have checked the return value from `wait()` before using your `status`.  A garbage value (`status` is uninitialized) could possibly evaluate `WIFEXITED(status)` to non-zero (true).  If `wait()` returns an error, you shouldn't rely on the value of `status`.  You can also use `errno` to check what went wrong (be sure to set `errno = 0` before the call to `wait()`).  See [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) for details.

### Some comments about pointers

The  lines

```
char *shmadd;
shmadd = (char *) 0;
```

are equivalent to `char *shmadd = NULL;`.  You don't have to type cast it.  (Do you even need the local variable `shmadd`? Can you just use `NULL` instead?)

Similarly, in

```
total = (shared_mem *) shmat (...)
```

you don't have to type cast the return value because it is a `void *`.  (C++ or C# might make you do this, but not in C.)

### Watch the variables

You have a second variable declaration of a variable named `k` that shadows the first one.  Here is the declaration of the second one:

```
while(total->flag[1] == TRUE && total->turn == 1)
{
  int k = 0;
  if(k = 0)
  {
    total->p2Block = total->p2Block + 1;
  }
  k++;
};
```

This `int k` shadows the earlier `k`.  Any reference to `k` in this block will use this one instead of the earlier one.  There are several other problems with this code:

- `if (k = 0)` is an assignment of 0 to `k`, not a comparison.  Since this evaluates to 0 (interpreted as false), the block will *never* be executed.  The `if` has no effect.
- If you change this to `if (k == 0)` (a comparison) it still makes no sense since it will *always* be true.  You just assigned 0 to `k` then check to see if `k` is 0.  Why would it change?
- The `k++` also has no logical meaning.  This `k` was declared at the beginning of the block, and its scope is just this block.  The next iteration of the `while` loop pushes a new `k` and initializes it to 0.  So there is no logical effect of incrementing it.
- Why write `total->p2Block = total->p2Block + 1` instead of just `total->p2Block++`?

This may explain why your counting is not behaving as intended.

Comment: I tried adding flag and turn to the shared_mem struct, however when I try to access it via total->flag[x] or total->turn I get an error: 'shared_mem' has no member named 'flag'. Which makes no sense to me because it's clearly a part of the struct now.

Comment: It's hard to determine why it would complain like that without seeing the actual code.  The basic idea remains: you must somehow share `flag` and `turn` to make it work.  As it is written in your question, they are not shared and each process only modifies and reads its own copy.  Without communication, there is no synchronization.

Comment: I've updated the code. It's been a few years since I've used C. I usually use C++ or C# now. I'm probably doing something wrong that I can't remember.

Comment: whoops, that was accidentally left in here. It wasn't in my code when I tried to compile it. I'll update it again.

Comment: So I just updated the code and it looks like I'm still having issues. First off: It appears that my processes are not interrupting one another. When I try the new code above it says that proccess 1 has interrupted process 2 0 times and vise versa. 

I'm also having trouble with the printing being out of order. End of Program prints before the info from process 1.

Comment: Are you allowed to just do `waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0); waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);` instead? It would be very simple.

Comment: I'll try that instead. I don't think I'm allowed too, but I'm not being taught anything in this class and I honestly don't care anymore as long as it works.

Comment: The processes still aren't interrupting one another. Or maybe my counting just isn't in the correct area? I'm clueless.

Comment: @JakeWilliams, Peterson's relies on some assumptions about propagation of changes to its shared variables that neither C nor POSIX guarantees to be justified.  You may have better luck in practice if you compile with all optimizations disabled, but you cannot really implement Peterson's correctly in C, because C provides no way to ensure that the algorithm's assumptions are satisfied.

Comment: @JohnBollinger This makes it a rather cruel assignment from the instructor. As you can see, most of my answer is just general coding complaints. I remember learning Peterson's, but I don't remember ever implementing it. It's worth teaching to introduce synchronization with busy waiting (which should lead to other methods), but I wouldn't assign it like this. It is good you pointed out its limitations. You can't truly understand something without knowing the limits of how to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

The `fork()` and `wait()` functions return `-1` when they fail.  You do not test for that.

Moreover, all processes involved in your program call `wait()`.  That call will certainly fail (returning `-1`) in at least one process, as regardless of the success or failure of the `fork()`'s, there will be one process without any child processes.

Your program has more serious problems, however.  It appears to assume that ordinary global variables `flag` and `turn` will be shared between processes, but since I see you using `shmget()`, I presume you know that that won't actually happen.

And even if you move `flag` and `turn` into your shared memory segment, you still have a synchronization problem: you cannot rely on one process to see the other's modifications to shared memory in a timely manner -- or, in fact, *ever* -- without employing appropriate synchronization.  The synchronization aid that naturally goes with SysV-style shared memory segments is the SysV-style semaphore.

And when you do implement synchronization, it should naturally fall out that you no longer need to use busy loops to make each process wait on the other.

Comment: [Peterson's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson's_algorithm) is frequently taught to introduce the student to synchronization. It uses only shared memory and programming logic the student should already know. It is just an expedient means to gain some understanding before later introducing more details such as busy waiting vs. blocking, hardware support for "compare & swap" instructions, etc. It's (usually) not intended as an ideal solution, but as a stepping stone in the learning process. By the time they learn the "real" methods, Peterson's Algorithm will seem silly.

Comment: It's for school, so it's what I have to use.

Comment: @e0k, that would all be well and good if it could be relied upon to *work*.  For that, Peterson's depends on modifications to the `turn` and `flag` variables propagating immediately and atomically between processes, **and you cannot safely rely on that to happen in this C implementation**.  Teaching the implementation of Peterson's without teaching the assumptions on which it relies seems to entirely miss the point.